# handling array inputs in aggregate query

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have a requirement to match names passed from frontend in mongodb database. 
If multiple names are passed from frontend, Im getting them as array through request. I'm trying to use $in to match the names passed from the frontend.

If i use for loop and form a dynamic variable, I'm not getting any result.

```
             nameList = NameDetails[0];

            for(var i=1; i< NameDetails.length; i++){

               nameList = nameList +"," +NameDetails[i].trim();

            }
```

or

```
            for(var i=1; i< NameDetails.length; i++){

               nameList = nameList + ",\""+NameDetails[i].trim()+"\"";

            }

NameDetail.aggregate([
                         { $match : {names: {$in: nameList } } },
                        ], function(err, res){
    //
}
```

If i directly access like below, I'm getting the result

```
NameDetail.aggregate([
                         { $match : {names: {$in: NameDetails[0], NameDetails[1]} } },
                        ], function(err, res){
    //
}
```

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `NameDetails` would appear to already be an "array", which is exactly what [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) takes as an argument. Why do you think you need to change this to a comma separated string or provide separate arguments? It takes an "array" of arguments.

Comment: can I use/write {$in: NameDetails } directly ? Thanks for your response.

Comment: Well if `NameDetails` is already an array of the values you want to select for that field then yes.

Comment: Thanks alot, it did the trick. It worked. I feel so dumb.

Comment: I was trying previously {$in: [NameDetails] }, i removed the square brackets and it worked.

Comment: Please Answer,  l Will mark it as answer.